# How to get a hover effect for glyphicon icons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-content

I'm trying to make glyphicon icon appear every time I hover my mouse over it. And I'm using `<span>` tag for it. But this refuses to work. What have I done wrong?

**application.scss**

```
 /*
 *= require bootstrap3-editable/bootstrap-editable
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker3
 *= require_tree .
 */

  @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
  @import "bootstrap";

.hovering:before {
display: none;
}

.hovering:hover:before {
display: block;
}
```

In my **view** file it looks like this:

```
  <span class='hovering'>
    <%= link_to user_task_path(current_user, task.id), method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true do %>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    <% end %>
  </span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Glyphicon icon isn't a pseudo-element on the `.hovering` element, it's a pseudo-element on the `i` element contained within. Because of this, we need to target the `i` element as well:

```css
.hovering i::before {
    display: none;
}

.hovering:hover i::before {
    display: block;
}
```